# read outputFile path (jenkins + gradle)

Tags: shell, jenkins, gradle

After calling `./gradlew assemble$Flavors`, I should know how to take outputFileName + full path. How I can take this information from the shell?

Comment: can you be more specific? what is your expectation ? and what is the current output?just my 10cent advise, a sample would be nice to start with ...

Comment: I need to get the path to the artifacts(output) through a shell